# How to find an element in vector of Option<String>

Tags: vector, rust, find, closures

As a rust newbie I have a problem finding an element in a vector of Option using the "find" function:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    name: Option<String>,
    data: Option<String>
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec=vec![
        MyStruct{
            name:Some(String::from("name1")),
            data:Some(String::from("data1"))
        },
        MyStruct{
            name:Some(String::from("name2")),
            data:Some(String::from("data2"))
        }
    ];
    let search_string = String::from("name2");
    let found_record=my_vec.iter().find(|s| s.name == Some(search_string));
    println!("{:?}", found_record);
}
```

This code does not compile because of the comparison s.name == Some(search_string) because of a missing Copy trait. What would be the correct way for the "find" expression?

Comment: Your question can be answered by [Cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662098/cannot-move-out-of-captured-outer-variable-in-an-fn-closure) and [Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233938/converting-from-optionstring-to-optionstr)

Comment: `my_vec.iter().find(|s| s.name.as_deref() == Some("name2"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to convert both your `search_string` and struct field to `Option<&str>` for comparison:

```
let found_record = my_vec.iter().find(
  |s| s.name.as_deref() == Some(search_string.as_ref()));
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=236e0b3e6a2af03622605936935af3d4)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there is difference if I use `Some(&search_string)` instead of the suggested `Some(search_string.as_ref())`? Both versions compile and return the correct answer.

Comment: They should be equivalent for your use case here. Just to notice that `Some(&search_string)` returns `Option<&String>` while the latter returns `Option<&str>`, they are different but both should give the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

**The Error cause**

Note that you are constructing an `Option` by using `Some()` inside the closure by moving the `String`.

---

**Some solutions**

1. You can avoid that moving and make the closure capture by immutable reference by constructing the `Option` before it, as follows

```
let search_string = Some(String::from("name2"));
let found_record=my_vec.iter().find( |s| s.name == search_string);
```

2. Or enter inside the `Option`, as follows

```
let search_string = String::from("name2");
let found_record=my_vec.iter().find( 
    |s| match &s.name{Some(name)=> name, _ => return false,} == &search_string
);
```

---

I don't prefer the approach

```
let found_record = my_vec.iter().find(
  |s| s.name.as_deref() == Some(search_string.as_ref()));
```

because it makes a new `Some()` every iteration unless if there is an optimization by the compiler.

Comment: @UdoEisenbarth If u mean in the 2nd case, Nope. Note that the result of the first match arm will be of type `&String` because you match over a `&Option<String>`, not an `Option<String>`